# mySQL C++ connector Visual Studio 2017

Tags: c++, mysql, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, mysql-connector

I am pretty new to Visual Studio.. Couldn't find similar topic so starting the new one.
I'm developig an MFC app and I'd like to use mySQL database engine.
I believe I have followed instructions from the official site to install the C++ connector:
[Building Connector/C++ Applications: General Considerations](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-cpp/8.0/en/connector-cpp-apps-general-considerations.html) and
[Building Connector/C++ Applications on Windows with Microsoft Visual Studio](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-cpp/8.0/en/connector-cpp-apps-windows-visual-studio.html)

i.e:

1. I downloaded c++ connector (together with mySQL database engine)
2. I chose to link dynamically against precompiled (by Oracle) c++ connector
   which means I need : LIB/vs14/mysqlcppconn8.lib (import library), LIB/mysqlcppconn8-1-vs14.dll
3. I selected debug mode in my configuration (according to the official docs I can do it even though the library itself may be compiled in release mode)
4. I added Additional Include Directories (Compiler->General) - which in my case is: "C:\Program Files\MySQL\Connector C++ 8.0\include" - this is where mysqlx/xdevapi.h resides
5. I added Additional Library Directories (Linker->General) - which in my case is: "C:\Program Files\MySQL\Connector C++ 8.0\lib64"
6. I added Additional Dependencies (Linker->Input) which in my case is mysqlcppconn8.lib (static import lib for the dll)
7. I changed option for Runtime Library (C++ -> Code Generation) from MDd to MT (as suggested in the documentation)
8. I extended the PATH env variable by adding the directory where the actual dll library is located (in my case the location of the file is C:\Program Files\MySQL\Connector C++ 8.0\lib64\mysqlcppconn8-1-vs14.dll so the path is C:\Program Files\MySQL\Connector C++ 8.0\lib64)
9. In the wizard-generated MFC project I added #include  and I get following error: fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'mysqlx/xdevapi.h': No such file or directory

I'm wondering what is causing this since I have added Include search path in step 4.

The directory structure for the library is as follows:

```
 C:\Program Files\MySQL\Connector C++ 8.0\include\mysqlx\xdevapi.h

 C:\Program Files\MySQL\Connector C++ 8.0\lib64\mysqlcppconn8-1-vs14.dll

 C:\Program Files\MySQL\Connector C++ 8.0\lib64\vs14\mysqlcppconn8.lib
```

The complier command:

```
 /Yu"stdafx.h" /GS /analyze- /W3 /Zc:wchar_t /I"C:\Program 
 Files\MySQL\Connector C++ 8.0\include\mysqlx" /I"C:\Program 
 Files\MySQL\Connector C++ 8.0\include" /ZI /Gm /Od /sdl 
 /Fd"Debug\vc141.pdb" /Zc:inline /fp:precise /D "WIN32" /D "_WINDOWS" /D 
 "_DEBUG" /D "_UNICODE" /D "UNICODE" /D "_AFXDLL" /errorReport:prompt /WX- 
 /Zc:forScope /RTC1 /Gd /Oy- /MT /Fa"Debug\" /EHsc /nologo /Fo"Debug\" 
 /Fp"Debug\exam-questions.pch" /diagnostics:classic
```

The linker command:

```
  /OUT:"C:\Users\Kamilek\source\repos\exam-questions\Debug\exam- 
  questions.exe" /MANIFEST /NXCOMPAT 
  /PDB:"C:\Users\Kamilek\source\repos\exam-questions\Debug\exam- 
  questions.pdb" /DYNAMICBASE "mysqlcppconn8.lib" /DEBUG:FASTLINK 
  /MACHINE:X86 /INCREMENTAL /PGD:"C:\Users\Kamilek\source\repos\exam- 
  questions\Debug\exam-questions.pgd" /SUBSYSTEM:WINDOWS 
  /MANIFESTUAC:"level='asInvoker' uiAccess='false'" 
  /ManifestFile:"Debug\exam-questions.exe.intermediate.manifest" 
  /ERRORREPORT:PROMPT /NOLOGO /LIBPATH:"C:\Program Files\MySQL\Connector 
  C++ 8.0\lib64\" /TLBID:1
```

Comment: Anyone? Everything is laid out, it should be pretty simple. It has to be some dummy mistake of mine..

Comment: Did you fix it ?

Comment: Nope, I didn't.